# Regex exclusion in C# Regex.Split()

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am writing a regex for `Regex.Split` in C#. Overall goal is to parse a file where I do not know the delimiters but I do know keywords. Every other word that is not a key word is an item. I have no way to tell how those will be delimited. So far I am using:

```
 String[] list = Regex.Split(line, @"\W+");
```

This works great except for a small caveat that one of the items is a hyphenated word. Is there a way to exclude the "-" character from being picked up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a negated character class.

```
String[] list = Regex.Split(line, @"[^-\w]+");
```

`[^-\w]+` negated character class which matches any character but not of a word char or hyphen (*one or more times*).

**OR**

```
String[] list = Regex.Split(line, @"(?:(?!-)\W)+");
```

Comment: One more question, this doesn't seem to filter out newline characters... I seem to get list = "Key" "Item" "Item" "Item" ""

Comment: `(?:(?!-)\W)+` is not a .NET way to restrict generic classes. Character class subtraction should be used.

Comment: For some reason i'm getting a blank item at the end of every list.

Comment: ya, splliting on last newline character will give you an empty string as an element. So first do strip and then do split.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that is using .NET regex character class subtraction:

```
String[] list = Regex.Split(line, @"[\W-[-]]+");
```

The `\W` is put into a character class, then we use a minus sign and use another subset of square parentheses to tell the regex engine to exclude some elements inside.

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5cW-%5b-%5d%5d%2b&i=look-ahead+and+look-behind+with%0d%0aa+newline)

[image]

You can add more exceptions into the nested character class if you want.